# Is there a way to use for loops (or nested for loops) to use date information from one dataframe and find the corresponding date from another df?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, date, nested

The following question is a rather general question. I have a data frame with certain individuals and some dates on the corresponding row. What I would like to do is using another daily data frame, find information pertaining to the consecutive days based on the date of the individual. For example, if I have individual X born on 01-01-2000 (1st df), using a function, I would like to find 01-01-2000 in the daily data frame (2nd df) and find the mean of the first 3 days post birth (namely 01-01-2000 : 05-01-2000) and then add it to a new column of the 1st df. Its not important what mean, it could be weight, sunlight hours, or number of calls. This question may be a bit vague so if someone could interpret this text, any help would be appreciated.

```
name<-c("A","B","C","D")
dob<-c("01-01-2000","02-01-2000","03-01-2000","08-01-2000")
df1<-data.frame(name,dob)

  name        dob
1    A 01-01-2000
2    B 02-01-2000
3    C 03-01-2000
4    D 08-01-2000

date<- c("31-12-1999","01-01-2000","02-01-2000","03-01-2000","04-01-2000","05-01-2000","06-01-2000","07-01-2000","08-01-2000","09-01-2000","10-01-2000","11-01-2000")
calls<-c(0,0,1,2,2,2,0,0,1,4,2,3)
df2<-data.frame(date,calls)

         date calls
1  31-12-1999     0
2  01-01-2000     0
3  02-01-2000     1
4  03-01-2000     2
5  04-01-2000     2
6  05-01-2000     2
7  06-01-2000     0
8  07-01-2000     0
9  08-01-2000     1
10 09-01-2000     4
11 10-01-2000     2
12 11-01-2000     3
```

What I would like is the following;

```
 name        dob mean.call
1    A 01-01-2000      1.00
2    B 02-01-2000      1.67
3    C 03-01-2000      2.00
4    D 08-01-2000      2.33
```

As the data frames are rather large, I would like to implement for loops.

Answer (score 0):

I would calculate the `mean`s first using `zoo`s `rollmean` function and then join `df2` and  `df1`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df2 %>%
  add_row(calls = rep(0, 2)) %>% 
  mutate(means = rollmean(calls, k = 3, align = "left", fill = NA),
         .keep = "unused") %>% 
  right_join(df1, by = c("date" = "dob")) %>% 
  select(name, date, means)
```

This returns

```r
  name       date    means
1    A 01-01-2000 1.000000
2    B 02-01-2000 1.666667
3    C 03-01-2000 2.000000
4    D 08-01-2000 2.333333
```

Note: I added two dummy rows into `df2` to calculate the `mean` of the last two entries. Since there is no specific rule for those values, I choose to do so. Keep this in mind.

Comment: Dear Martin Gal, thank you for your response. It did work for smaller subsets of the data, however, when tried to extrapolate to the larger dataset with more than thousand dates, it does not seem to work. For the time being, if I ignore the latter requirement (i.e. matching it to the name), is it possible to get a mean for each row which computes the mean for the following year from that date. (e.g. 1-1-2000 --> mean(1-1-2000:1-1-2001),2-1-2000-->mean(2-1-2000:2-1-2001) and so on.

Comment: For example, I would like to include it in this format;                                                                  for (i in 1:length(daily_calls$date)) {
  daily_calls$annual_mean[[i]]<- mean(daily_calls$call_number[i],daily_calls$call_number[i+365])
}. I know the syntax is incorrect (as the error I get is this; Error in if (trim > 0 && n) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed) but I would like to write something along these lines. Especially using [i] and [i:365+1]